# Laravel 5.1 on ubuntu 14.04 Problems with session

Tags: php, session, laravel, ubuntu-14.04, laravel-5.1

I've got the following problem with laravel (5.1) sessions on ubuntu 14.04. On every request a new session file in storage/framework/sessions is generated. As you have already guessed, the session driver is 'file', 'lifetime' is set to 120. This seems to be some sort of permission error. I've set the permission of the storage folder to 755 (also 777), but every newly generated session file has the permission 664 (rw- rw- r--). Via google I've only found a session issue related to dd(...), but this is not the case here, especially that it works fine on a windows environment. 
What I originally wanted to do is use the redirect()->intended(), which uses the information stored in the session.

Do I have to run php artisan serve in a special way?

Comment: can you show the error message ?

Comment: It appears no error. redirect()->intended('dashboard') just uses the given fallback route when it doesnt find 'url.intended' in the session: $this->session->pull('url.intended', $default); The second symptom is that on every request a new session file is generated so that no information can be persisted anyway

Comment: That is not the session intended behavior. strange though. try clear cache, and dump autoload.

Comment: That didn't help. I also tried to 'composer install' it again.

Comment: You said that you set the permissions to the storage folder, but also did you set the permissions to all of the subfolders of storage? (app, framework, session ...)

Comment: Yeah, I did that recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I use Vagrant and Homestead everything is fine. Running the PHP built in webserver seems the be a kludge only.

Answer (score 0):

Test the funcionality giving all the permissions to the storage folder

```
find /path/to/storage/folder -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

If it works then set the propper permissions that in most of the cases should be

```
find /path/to/storage/folder -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

That way you only change the permissions to the directories not the files.

If the problem it's the newly created are being set with different owner you could set the permission for it.

It's like when I'm developing on my local server I have my user and the www-data user it's the one for Apache, so if apache creates a new file the ownership starts to mess up.

```
find /path/to/root/of/project -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
```

Comment: Did not help. The folders permission was already good. I guess that the problem is that those newly spawned session files have not the right permission. They are only 664, but I have no clue why.

Comment: Ok so check the owner and the group of those new files, if they are different than the ones for the folder then use the command that I will put on the answer

Comment: The files have the same owner and group. By the way, the process owner of the started laravel server is the same.